# How to get HFile size of a HBase table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hfile

I am trying to get few metrics details of HFile in HBase. The following are the questions.

1. how to get actual location of the HFile for a Hbase table.
2. Is there any shell command to get the consolidated file size.

I understand the Hfile is stored in HDFS, so the data is stored as blocks, in different data nodes. But how to get the consolidated data from an HBase point of view.

Comment: Your question shows a lack of basic understanding concerning HFiles & HBase tables. You should either rephrase it to make sense or delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Hbase table data is stored on hdfs as you said. 
the default location of table data on hdfs is /hbase/data/default path.
you can use

```
hadoop fs -dus /user/hbase/data/*
```

command for the total size of your table. Go to the folder of your table under this path for the hfiles. for the size of hfiles you can use the command above or  check hbase master page. you can find all of your region names and their sizes.

Comment: It helped, but i can see many sub folders inside my table folder and with details of which server is the data on. How to get individual infomration